# how to access form's data in a django formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have problem on accessing the form data from a formset. I attached the code:

```
####FORM
class ActionTypeForm(forms.Form):
     action_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)


####VIEW
dataset = request.POST
ActionTypeFormSet = formset_factory(ActionTypeForm)
formset = ActionTypeFormSet(dataset)

if formset.is_valid():
     for form in formset.cleaned_data:  #I ALSO TESETED formset.forms
           customer.create_actiontype(form['action_name'], form['description'])
```

the error is I can't get form['action_name'].  formset.is_valid() return True

## ERROR

Exception Type:     KeyError

Exception Value:    'action_name'

## POST DATA

form-0-action_name  u'a'

form-2-description  u'sadsa'

form-0-description  u'a'

form-MAX_NUM_FORMS  u''

form-1-description  u'asd'

form-TOTAL_FORMS    u'3'

form-1-action_name  u'as'

form-INITIAL_FORMS  u'0'

csrfmiddlewaretoken     u'c4fa9ddb4ec69ac639d7801eb14979f2'

form-2-action_name  u'asda'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you have a blank form. You are using model fields in your form class definition, which django's forms framework has no idea what to do with. Django models != django forms.

The formset is validating and returning empty forms which of course have no form fields.

You should either create `Formset`s out of forms with valid form fields, or `ModelFormset`s out of `Model`s.

- Update: I initially thought that formsets don't have `cleaned_data`, but I guess they do return a list of cleaned_datas of all forms, which means the problem with your code is just the above.

Answer (score 0):

The formset stores all it's associated forms in `self.forms` and iterating over it will return an iterator `iter(self.forms)` for the forms.

Your `POST` data looks good, so this is how you can make it work:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset: 
        customer.create_actiontype(form.action_name, form.description)
```

Comment: This will throw an `AttributeError`, as forms don't implement their bound fields as attributes but via item indexing (form['action_name']) and finally the data itself will be in the `cleaned_data` dict.